# Google Cloud Sql SQL Alchemy not insert data

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud Sql Istance (Postgres), and I'm trying to create and insert data, using SqlAlchemy from Python
This is my code:

```
import os
import sqlalchemy
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes

db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]  
db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]  
db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]  
instance_connection_name = os.environ["INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"]


# initialize Connector object
connector = Connector()



def getconn():
    with Connector() as connector:
        conn = connector.connect(
            instance_connection_name,
            "pg8000",
            user = db_user,
            password = db_pass,
            db = db_name,
            ip_type = IPTypes.PUBLIC
        )
        return conn


# create connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
    pool_size=20,
    max_overflow=2,
    pool_timeout=30,
    pool_recycle=1800
)

with pool.connect() as db_conn:
  # create ratings table in our sandwiches database
  db_conn.execute(
    sqlalchemy.text(
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings "
      "( id SERIAL NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "
      "origin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, rating FLOAT NOT NULL, "
      "PRIMARY KEY (id));"
    )
  )
  # insert data into our ratings table
  insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.text(
      "INSERT INTO ratings (name, origin, rating) VALUES (:name, :origin, :rating)",
  )

  # insert entries into table
  db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"name": "HOTDOG", "origin": "Germany", "rating": 7.5})
  db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"name": "BÀNH MÌ", "origin": "Vietnam", "rating": 9.1})
  db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"name": "CROQUE MADAME", "origin": "France", "rating": 8.3})

  # query and fetch ratings table
  results = db_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * FROM ratings")).fetchall()

  # show results
  for row in results:
    print(row)
```

The code works fine into console and not have errors, but into db i don't have the table with value inserted.
There's something to config into google cloud sql?
If i run the SQL statement into postgres from command line, the statement works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dev_ looks like you found a bug in the documentation! SQLAlchemy v2.x.x is commit as you go, which means `.commit()` must be called to commit the transactions back to the DB.

Add `db_conn.commit()` should resolve the issue and have the data appear in the database.

The code would look like:

```py
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
  # create ratings table in our sandwiches database
  db_conn.execute(
    sqlalchemy.text(
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings "
      "( id SERIAL NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "
      "origin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, rating FLOAT NOT NULL, "
      "PRIMARY KEY (id));"
    )
  )
  # commit transaction
  db_conn.commit()

  # insert data into our ratings table
  insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.text(
      "INSERT INTO ratings (name, origin, rating) VALUES (:name, :origin, :rating)",
  )

  # insert entries into table
  db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"name": "HOTDOG", "origin": "Germany", "rating": 7.5})
  db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"name": "BÀNH MÌ", "origin": "Vietnam", "rating": 9.1})
  db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, parameters={"name": "CROQUE MADAME", "origin": "France", "rating": 8.3})

  # commit transactions
  db_conn.commit()

  # query and fetch ratings table
  results = db_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * FROM ratings")).fetchall()

  # show results
  for row in results:
    print(row)
```

I've submitted a PR to have this change showcased in the documentation: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/pull/686

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your reply. Your response is correct. Using the commit() the data is inserted into db. Thanks